# Error with Symbolicatecrash in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode9, symbolicatecrash

I've been trying to use symobolicatecrash in Xcode 9 to symbolicate user supplied OS X crash logs.  Based on my research, it's usage seems pretty straight forward.  However, I can't get past this error:

```
     Unsupported crash log version: 12 at .../symbolicatecrash line 619
```

When I check the log file, I find that it is indeed Report Version 12. When I open symbolicatecrash in Xcode I find the offending code:

```
    if(! $is_spindump_report) {
    if($report_version == 102 || $report_version == 103) { # Leopard GM
        $pat = '
            ^\s* (\w+) \s* \- \s* (\w+) \s*     (?# the range base and extent [1,2] )
            (\+)?                               (?# the application may have a + in front of the name [3] )
            (.+)                                (?# bundle name [4] )
            \s+ .+ \(.+\) \s*                   (?# the versions--generally "??? [???]" )
            \<?([[:xdigit:]]{32})?\>?           (?# possible UUID [5] )
            \s* (\/.*)\s*$                      (?# first fwdslash to end we hope is path [6] )
            ';
        %captures = ( 'base' => \$1, 'extent' => \$2, 'plus' => \$3,
        'bundlename' => \$4, 'uuid' => \$5, 'path' => \$6);
    }
    elsif($report_version == 104 || $report_version == 105) { # Kirkwood
        # 0x182155000 - 0x1824c6fff CoreFoundation arm64  <f0d21c6db8d83cf3a0c4712fd6e69a8e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
        $pat = '
        ^\s* (\w+) \s* \- \s* (\w+) \s*     (?# the range base and extent [1,2] )
        (\+)?                               (?# the application may have a + in front of the name [3] )
        (.+)                                (?# bundle name [4] )
        \s+ ('.$architectures.') \s+        (?# the image arch [5] )
        \<?([[:xdigit:]]{32})?\>?           (?# possible UUID [6] )
        \s* (\/.*)\s*$                      (?# first fwdslash to end we hope is path [7] )
        ';
        %captures = ( 'base' => \$1, 'extent' => \$2, 'plus' => \$3,
        'bundlename' => \$4, 'arch' => \$5, 'uuid' => \$6,
        'path' => \$7);
    }
    else {
        die "Unsupported crash log version: $report_version";
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, OS X crash logs are currently version 12, and older reports are versions 11, 10, 9 ... I'm not a PERL expert, but it seems that with this code, symbolicatecrash will never work. It seems to be looking for report versions 102, 103, 104, or 105.  I've found a number of turorials/guides that explain how to use symbolicatecrash so it seems to be working for some people.

Can anyone help figure out what is going on.  I noticed that the code was copyrighted 2008-2015, so maybe this is an old version, but I found this in Xcode 9.4.1.  Or perhaps is symbolicatecrash only for iOS crash logs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like symbolicating using this script is not supported on the iOS Simulator. If you take a look at crash logs obtained from a device the version is 105

```
OS Version:          iOS 13.0 (17A5522g)
Report Version:      105
```

which maps to the perl script:

`elsif($report_version == 104 || $report_version == 105) { # Kirkwood`

where as on iOS simulator the report version is

```
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.4 (18E226)
Report Version:        12
```

This is frustrating because crash logs happen during unit testing and ui testing where no debugger has been attached. so symbolication of iOS simulator would be nice